# Series where the sum is 0

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

I'm not a mathematician and don't know a lot about series but I'm trying to figure out if there is an infinite geometric series that starts at 1 (or any other positive number), has fractions always subtracted from it, and has a sum of 0.

Comment: What does it mean to have "fractions always subtracted from it"?

Comment: The values that are subtracted are always fractions where the denominator is increasing

Comment: Does $1 - 1/2 - 1/4 - 1/8 - \cdots$ answer your question?

Comment: That’s the series I was thinking about as a possibility but is the sum 0?

Comment: Yes. The infinite sum is (by definition) the limit of the finite partial sums.

Comment: So you want the first term to be positive and all of the remaining terms to be negative rational numbers? (numerator $1$ too?)

Comment: Yes I want the first to be positive and the remaining to be negative rational numbers.

Comment: Worth noting that whenever $\sum_{i=0}^\infty b_i$ converges to $L$, the series $L-b_0-b_1\dots$ converges to $0$.  So you need not restrict your attention to geometric series or any other special kind to get examples summing to $0$.

Comment: Could you please show me the proof for one such series and why it sums to 0?

Comment: @harris Ethan Bolker's example works - if you want examples that aren't geometric then you could take something like $b_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$.  As for why the series sums to $0$, that's just immediate from writing $$\lim_{k\to \infty}\left( L- \sum_{i=0}^k b_k\right)= L - \lim_{k\to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^k b_k = L-L =0.$$

Comment: Thank you! I have one more question because I think I’ve confused myself. What exactly is the difference between converging to 0 and the sum being 0?

Answer (score 2):

*Because MSE would [prefer not to have questions answered solely in the comments](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29851/having-a-check-sign-for-questions-addressed-but-not-answered), it is [recommended](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4426/405572) to [transfer the most helpful comments to a bona-fide answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/dealing-with-answers-in-comments#comment5417_1560). I can make this answer [CW (community-wiki)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/dealing-with-answers-in-comments#comment5417_1560) upon request.*

---

A comment by [@Ethan Bolker] said that $1-\frac 12 - \frac 14 - \frac 18 - \ldots$ is an infinite series that converges to $0$.

A comment by [@M W] remarked that more generally, for any infinite series $\sum_{i=0}^\infty b_i$ which converges to $L$, the infinite series $L-b_0-b_1-b_2-\ldots$ converges to $0$.

---

**Since the OP asked in the comments about this:** if we have an infinite sum $\sum_{i=0}^\infty b_i$, the phrases:

- the infinite series $\sum_{i=0}^\infty b_i$ converges to/approaches $L$
- the infinite sum $\sum_{i=0}^\infty b_i$ equals/evaluates to $L$
- the partial sums $b_0, b_0+b_1, b_0+b_1+b_2, \ldots, \sum_{i=0}^n b_i, \ldots$ converge to/approach $L$

***ALL mean the same thing***, and can be interchangeably used. Usually, if we write an expression which ends with "dot dot dot", e.g. $1+\frac 12+\frac 14 + \ldots$, we *typically* would say that "converges to/approaches" the limit $L$ instead of it "equals" $L$, but saying "equals" is also fine (I wouldn't say it's wrong, but "converges to" just sounds a bit better).

---

**I maybe can also add a picture to this discussion.** In the below picture, we have purple squares of area $(\frac 12)^2, (\frac 14)^2, \ldots$ (in decreasing order). Because there are a total of 3 squares of the same dimensions (a purple square, with a yellow squares directly above and to the right of it, all of the same dimensions), the total sum of the purple areas is $L:=\frac 13$.

So, you can imagine that we have the purple region with area $L=\frac 13$, and we start taking away squares one by one (taking the biggest one first, and so on). Then eventually taking away all the purple squares we get $\frac 13- (\frac 12)^2 - (\frac 14)^2- \ldots$ converges to $0$.

[image: Geometric series summing to 1/3]